# OpenID "AOL is unable to verify this website."

Tags: openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get AOL's OpenID site verification to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505638/how-do-you-get-aols-openid-site-verification-to-work)

Trying to use AOL as openid provider you get this message "AOL is unable to verify this website."
When searching for this on google
http://www.google.com/search?q=%22AOL+is+unable+to+verify+this+website.%22

How does one make AOL verify a site?
[this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505638/how-do-you-get-aols-openid-site-verification-to-work) does not help answer it...

Comment: Why was this migrated to SO? I don't see how this is a programming question.  How is something being openid-and-AOL related automatically a programming question. Voted to close.

Comment: This is both a duplicate of the linked question, and hardly on topic, since it requires you to contact AOL and ask them why their openid implementation is busted.

Comment: I did not ask the question on SO as it was a question trying to understand what AOL needs a webmaster to do in order to recognize a website as Verified. The StackOverflow question does not answer the question on what needs to be done in order to make this message disapear. I didn't expect it to be programming related. Probably need to go through some kind of Api registration or something. Please move back to Webmasters or the site that will answer that.